# Vice output freezes on startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, freeze, gui

On Ubuntu Jammy 22.04, I have installed `vice`:

```
ii  vice           3.6.1+dfsg-2 amd64        Versatile Commodore Emulator
```

I have also installed the emulator data files from the corresponding source tarball to `/usr/share/vice`.

If I start e.g. `x64`, the Vice window pops up,and I am able to open the menus, but the main screen area is black, not showing anything.

If I switch to another workspace and then switch back, then the whole window's contents are garbled (they show a screenshot of the previously active workspace). If I then use a keyboard shortcut to close the window, it does pop up the usual "Do you really wish to exit VICE?" dialog, so the whole program doesn't seem frozen, only its video output.

What is going wrong?

Below is the full log of `x64 -verbose`:

```
Hotkeys: Initializing.
Hotkeys: Parsing C64 hotkeys file:
Hotkeys: OK.
ffmpeg avformat lib has version 3a4c64, VICE expects 3a4c64: full match
ffmpeg  avcodec lib has version 3a8664, VICE expects 3a8664: full match
ffmpeg   avutil lib has version 384664, VICE expects 384664: full match
ffmpeg  swscale lib has version 050964, VICE expects 050964: full match
ffmpeg swresample lib has version 030964, VICE expects 030964: full match
Detecting ISA HardSID boards.
Could not open '/dev/port'.
Cannot get permission to access $300.
Detecting PCI HardSID boards.
No PCI HardSID boards found.
Detecting PCI CatWeasel boards.
No PCI CatWeasel found.
Detecting direct I/O ISA SSI2001.
Could not open '/dev/port'.
Cannot get permission to access $280.
Hotkeys: parsing '/home/cactus/.config/vice/gtk3-hotkeys-C64.vhk':
Reading configuration file `/home/cactus/.config/vice/vicerc'.
 
*** VICE Version 3.6.1 ***
 
Welcome to x64, the free portable C64 Emulator.
 
Current VICE team members:
Martin Pottendorfer, Marco van den Heuvel, Fabrizio Gennari, Groepaz, 
Errol Smith, Ingo Korb, Olaf Seibert, Marcus Sutton, Kajtar Zsolt, AreaScout, 
Bas Wassink, Michael C. Martin, Christopher Phillips, David Hogan, 
Empathic Qubit, Roberto Muscedere, June Tate-Gans, Pablo Roldan.
 
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
See the "About VICE" command for more info.
 
random seed was: 0x654f7f12
command line was: x64
Loading system file `/usr/share/vice/C64/kernal'.
Loading system file `/usr/share/vice/C64/basic'.
Loading system file `/usr/share/vice/C64/chargen'.
Loading system file `/usr/share/vice/PRINTER/mps803'.
Palette: Loading palette `/usr/share/vice/PRINTER/mps803.vpl'.
Loading system file `/usr/share/vice/PRINTER/nl10-cbm'.
Palette: Loading palette `/usr/share/vice/PRINTER/nl10.vpl'.
NL10: Printer driver initialized.
Palette: Loading palette `/usr/share/vice/PRINTER/1520.vpl'.
Loading system file `/usr/share/vice/DRIVES/dos1540'.
Loading system file `/usr/share/vice/DRIVES/dos1541'.
Loading system file `/usr/share/vice/DRIVES/d1541II'.
Loading system file `/usr/share/vice/DRIVES/dos1570'.
Loading system file `/usr/share/vice/DRIVES/dos1571'.
Loading system file `/usr/share/vice/DRIVES/dos1581'.
DriveROM: Error - 2000 ROM image not found. Hardware-level 2000 emulation is not available.
DriveROM: Error - 4000 ROM image not found. Hardware-level 4000 emulation is not available.
DriveROM: Error - CMDHD ROM image not found. Hardware-level CMDHD emulation is not available.
Loading system file `/usr/share/vice/DRIVES/dos2031'.
Loading system file `/usr/share/vice/DRIVES/dos2040'.
Loading system file `/usr/share/vice/DRIVES/dos3040'.
Loading system file `/usr/share/vice/DRIVES/dos4040'.
Loading system file `/usr/share/vice/DRIVES/dos1001'.
Loading system file `/usr/share/vice/DRIVES/dos9000'.
Drive: Finished loading ROM images.
using GTK3 backend: OpenGL
GLX version: 1.4
Getting matching framebuffer configs
Found 64 matching FB configs.
Obtained OpenGL 4.6 context
      Vendor: Intel
    Renderer: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
     Version: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
      Legacy: no
Direct GLX rendering context obtained
Swap control support. glXSwapIntervalMESA: 1 glXSwapIntervalEXT: 1 glXSwapIntervalSGI: 1
Loading vertex shader: /usr/share/vice/GLSL/viewport.vert
Loading fragment shader: /usr/share/vice/GLSL/builtin.frag
Loading vertex shader: /usr/share/vice/GLSL/viewport.vert
Loading fragment shader: /usr/share/vice/GLSL/builtin-interlaced.frag
Loading vertex shader: /usr/share/vice/GLSL/viewport.vert
Loading fragment shader: /usr/share/vice/GLSL/bicubic.frag
Loading vertex shader: /usr/share/vice/GLSL/viewport.vert
Loading fragment shader: /usr/share/vice/GLSL/bicubic-interlaced.frag
Created render thread 0
Render thread initialised
opening dynamic library libmp3lame.so failed!
ERROR setting up dynamic lame lib!
Sound: Available sound devices: pulse alsa dummy fs dump wav voc iff aiff mp3 soundmovie
Joystick: Linux joystick interface initialization...
Joystick: Warning - Cannot open joystick device `/dev/input/js0'.
Joystick: Warning - Cannot open joystick device `/dev/input/js1'.
Joystick: Warning - Cannot open joystick device `/dev/input/js2'.
Joystick: Warning - Cannot open joystick device `/dev/input/js3'.
Joystick: Warning - Cannot open joystick device `/dev/input/js4'.
Joystick: Warning - Cannot open joystick device `/dev/input/js5'.
Joystick: Warning - Cannot open joystick device `/dev/input/js6'.
Joystick: Warning - Cannot open joystick device `/dev/input/js7'.
Keyboard: Loading keymap `/usr/share/vice/C64/gtk3_sym.vkm'.
Main CPU: starting at ($FFFC).
Main CPU: RESET.
Sound: Opened device `pulse', speed 48000Hz, fragment size 2.67ms, buffer size 101.33ms
reSID: MOS8580, filter on, sampling rate 48000Hz - resampling, pass to 21600Hz
Sync reset
Unit 8: RESET.
```